# How to join two tables with null values in referenced fields

Tags: c#, linq, .net-4.5

The table t1("PO1") and the t2("DTM") contains following values

```
Table t1
PO101(string)       Loop_Id (Int)
Item_1              6     
Item_2              8
---
Table t2
DTM02(string)       Loop_Id(int)
20141029            (null)
20141029            6
20141101            8
```

This query

```
  var records = (from t1 in x12.InterchangeDataSet.Tables["PO1"].AsEnumerable()
                 join t2 in x12.InterchangeDataSet.Tables["DTM"].AsEnumerable() 
                 on  t1.Field<string>("Loop_Id") equals t2.Field<string>("Loop_Id") 
                 select new{A = t1.Field<string>("PO101"),B=t2.Field<string>("DTM02")});
```

Fails with

```
base {System.SystemException} = 
{"Cannot cast DBNull.Value to type 'System.Int32'. Please use a nullable type."}
```

becasue of the null value in the t2.Loop_id.

If I remove the row containing null value in the t2, it works fine.

How do I either cast the Loop_Id to be nullable or avoid joining rows that has null in either of the table ?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution

```
 var records = (from t1 in x12.InterchangeDataSet.Tables["PO1"].AsEnumerable()
                           join t2 in x12.InterchangeDataSet.Tables["DTM"].AsEnumerable()  on t1.Field<Nullable<int>>("Loop_Id")
                           equals (t2.Field<Nullable<int>>("Loop_Id"))
                           select new{A = t1.Field<string>("PO101"),B=t2.Field<string>("DTM02")}
                           );
```

Comment: @paqoginez, it is derived from your answer, thanks. As you see the use of static nullable cast eliminates the need for where clause too.

Comment: @paqogomez, I dont see your answer anymore !.

Answer (score 0):

```
  var records = (from t1 in x12.InterchangeDataSet.Tables["PO1"].AsEnumerable()
                 join t2 in x12.InterchangeDataSet.Tables["DTM"].AsEnumerable() 
                 on t1.Field<string>("Loop_Id") 
                 equals (t2.Field<string>("Loop_Id") == null 
                    ? string.Emtpty : t2.Field<string>("Loop_Id"))
                select new{A = t1.Field<string>("PO101"),B=t2.Field<string>("DTM02")});
```

I think it should work. Please try.

Answer (score 0):

Use below query to handle null.

```
var records = (from t1 in x12.InterchangeDataSet.Tables["PO1"].AsEnumerable()
               join t2 in x12.InterchangeDataSet.Tables["DTM"].AsEnumerable() 
               on t1.Field<int>("Loop_Id") equals t2.Field<int>("Loop_Id") 
               where t2.Field<int>("Loop_Id") != null
               select new{A = t1.Field<string>("PO101"),B=t2.Field<string>("DTM02")});
```

Comment: This fails now with base {System.SystemException} = {"Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.String'."}

Comment: Nop, now it throws: {"Cannot cast DBNull.Value to type 'System.Int32'. Please use a nullable type."}